# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания в двух предложениях?

Tags: пунктуация

Защитник Иванова И. И. адвокат Петров П. П. выразил свою позицию по делу.

Защитник Иванова И. И. Петров П. П. выразил свою позицию по делу.

Comment: может быть не выразил, а выразили? Смысл предложения не очень ясен...

Answer (score 1):

А зачем вам понадобились тут знаки препинания? Они не нужны.

Comment: Тире разве не нужно ставить ??

Comment: @Валерий: где тире? Два "?" подряд точно не надо. Есть "?!".

Comment: Защитник Иванова И. И. - адвокат Петров П. П. выразил свою позицию по делу.

Comment: Не так ли правильно будет?

Comment: Нет, тире лишнее тут, на мой взгляд.

Comment: Спасибо за мнение!