Нужно ли ставить тире после слов «Иванова И.И.»?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли в этих предложениях ставить тире после слов «Иванова И.И.»? Если да, то в каком именно:
Представитель Иванова И.И. - адвокат Петров П.П. изложил свою позицию по делу.
Защитник Иванова И.И. - Петров П.П. изложил свою позицию по делу.

ФИО в тексте документа не повторяют, заменяя на термины Истец/Представитель Истца и Ответчик/Представитель Ответчика.

@Валерий М-м... Точно такой вопрос уже был. (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/471623/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85)

Есть сомнения относительно прошлого ответа по первому указанному предложению!

Вариант оформления:

Представитель Иванова И.И. — адвокат Петров П.П. // изложил свою позицию по делу.  Одно тире опускается.

Защитник Иванова И.И. Петров П.П. // изложил свою позицию по делу.  Приложение + имя собственное.


Пояснение
Розенталь, пункт 10
Пункт 10. При обособлении приложений вместо запятой употребляется тире.
Примечание. Одно тире (первое или второе) опускается: 2) если приложение выражает конкретное значение, а предшествующее определяемое слово имеет общее или образное значение: На совещании министров иностранных дел стран — членов Организации американских государств выступил министр иностранных дел Кубы (Газ.);
Примечание. Допускается написание (1) без обособления  Представитель Иванова И.И. адвокат Петров П.П. // изложил свою позицию по делу.  Розенталь, пункт 2.

Спасибо за четкий и понятный ответ!
